# CSS Loading Local Background Image

Tags: html, css, django

[Folder Struc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/464D5.jpg)This is so simple, but nothing is working for me. I am trying to have a background of a local picture I own. I have read a bunch of other sites, and no one is consistent. I have tried every combo of ../ or ./ or file/// or someone even said web/port_back. Half include "" within the () and half don't. Tried every combo with that. Cleared my cache data constantly just in case that has affected it.

My Image is located /Portfolio/port_back.JPG and
My css is located /Portfolio/static/index_app/index.css

CSS:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("../../port_back.jpg");
  /* background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: It will help us a lot if you share your folder structure to the project. Also, what bundler you use?

Comment: it depends - what is the size of your picture? is your server case sensitive? background of some other element may be overriding the color. do you have content inside body to get some width and height so that the background picture should be displayed

Comment: Please inspect in browser the , check the url of image.

Comment: Waqas Raja - 877 x 433 px...Rayees AC - It says image not found in my terminal

Comment: Also, I keep getting this error - Not Found: /favicon.ico

Answer (score 4):

You should go 3 folders back, try:

```
background-image: url("../../../port_back.jpg");
```